# Angularjs + call methods by string

Tags: angularjs

I have dynamically generated input elements with unique Id. I need to bind click event for each input element which will perform different action.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to post something that shows what you have tried. You'll just see downvotes otherwise!

Comment: You can have single handler and pass the input control id. Then perform different actions depending on which input was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean call methods on the controller scope dynamically, you want something like this:

```
$scope.callFn = function(fn) {
    $scope[fn]();
}
```

then

```
<input ng-click="callFn(foo)" />
```

but you really need a lot more detail in your question to give a better answer.